# Photo not loading in markdown python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I've recently began coding for my degree and for a project I am submitting it via a pdf created in Jupyter so that my code can be seen. It all works within Jupyter but when I export to PDF the image that I have embedded in markdown doesn't load. All that loads in Microsoft edge is a small black box with a white cross in and in chrome there is a small image of mountains in two pieces. I am not sure where I'm going wrong. My image is written in like this:

```
<img src="files/masterbiaspic.png" />
```

And I don't know how to fix it.
I really don't have a wide knowledge of code so please be simple with your answers.

Kind regards and happy new year,

E

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using raw HTML to insert your images into your document. What you may not know is that most Markdown parsers do not look at the contents of raw HTML, they simply pass it through unaltered. However, raw HTML is not understood by the PDF file format, and in fact, when converting to PDF, there is no clean way to convert raw HTML to PDF without also parsing the HTML (which is beyond the scope of Markdown parsers). Therefore, if you want to output to PDF, you should only use pure Markdown (without any raw HTML). That way the parser can easily convert everything to a proper format for PDF output.

As it turns out, Markdown includes its own syntax for images (see the [documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img) for details). Try this:

```
![alt text](files/masterbiaspic.png)
```

By doing that, Jupyter Notebook will know about the image and should import it into the PDF properly.

It could be that the above will not resolve the problem. It depends on which method is used to convert to PDF. Some tools may take the HTML output of Markdown and convert that to PDF, which would mean you have a different problem entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping Waylan, unfortunatley this hasn't soled my problem, instead of converting to PDF i'm downloading to HTML then I will change it to PDF. I understand what you are saying about the misunderstanding but it hasn't fixed my problem :/ Thank you again

Comment: I've decided to not use an image but to instead use the actual code. Thank you for your help! :)